# Any other local or push Notification detection while application running

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios5

I want to know that is there any way that when my application keeps running. And device receive any type of local or push badge notification then my application will give a custom alert. That an application received a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Your application can only respond to notifications meant for it... it can do nothing about notifications received by other apps...

Comment: I want to detect notification only that device received something else.